# What is a "_e" or "_vs" Google Tag Manager event?

Tags: ios, swift, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

I see these in my console output in Xcode but they don't correspond to any events I am explicitly sending.  They are just littering up the debug output and I'd like to get rid of them.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpYfR.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIALz.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"_e" is [user_engagement](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event) event and "_vs" is screen_view event. Both are internal automatic events. Active users and user engagement reports are based on user_engagement event. Screen reporting is based on screen_view events.

Comment: Is there any way to silence those logs?  I have -FIRDebugDisabled in my scheme, hoping it would help.

Comment: Those are core events that power almost all of the Firebase Analytics reporting. There is no switch to just turn off them as this will practically be equivalent to removing Firebase Analytics from your app. Please note that logging the events doesnt result in network request. The data is stored locally and batch uploaded at a later time so there is no measurable impact on battery or data usage.

Comment: It's not that I want to turn off those core events, I just don't want to hear about them via my console.  Good to know those aren't doing extra network calls though.

Comment: Those are only logged when you enable Firebase Analytics debug logging for your app. In production or until you enable Firebase Analytics debug logging the events are not logged in the device logs and do not consume additional resources.

Comment: When running my app on the simulator is there a way to disable logging?  I tried -FIRDebugDisabled but I still see the outputs to the console.